# What better way?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning

With this sentence

> **What better way to** celebrate the peace **than** with a fight?

Is "what better way to" an informal phrase? Would it be better to write

> What is better than fighting as a way to celebrate the peace?

Comment: No, the original sentence is notably superior.

Comment: I think suggesting, whether seriously or ironically, that fighting is a good way to celebrate peace would be where a sense of informality is coming in here.

Comment: Can it be put in formal writing?

Comment: @JonHanna It isn’t clear whether the OP is concerned with syntax or sentiment here. Their rewrite leads me to suspect they worry that the original sentence “has no verb”, and so would incur the unjust ire of shortsighted copyeditors and Microsoft Word alike.

Comment: I'm worried that it would seem to informal for an essay.

Comment: Can't the same sentiment be drawn from both?

Comment: @user36521 The grammar of the original is as sound as it is succinct. Its replacement is much weaker.

Comment: Right. It doesn't sound right to me for some reason. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

> What better way to celebrate the peace than with a fight?

This phrasing highlights the irony in the statement (a fight celebrates peace) by juxtaposing the words in close proximity.

"What better way" is an English idiom which is rhetorical. The question doesn't literally ask for a better way, it posits that there is no better way. I don't feel the idiom is particularly informal, I don't think you should worry about using it in formal writing.

> What is better than fighting as a way to celebrate the peace?

This phrasing sounds needlessly clunky, and comes across sounding like you are seriously asking for a better means of celebrating the peace, since fighting is clearly not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In studying the phrase "What better way", I have found that it is a commonly used phrase since edwardian times in English jargon and is considered proper when followed by a validation. "What better way, than to jump in head first".

Answer (score 1):

*What better way ...* is elliptic not for *What would be a better way ...*, but for *What better way could there be ...*.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence (question) you provided is a part of some conversation or writing, and seems like it should be understood in some context.

To me, it seems something (at least) deviating from the actual discussion. Such things/feelings/opinions should normally be short so as to not disturb the pace and intensity of the discussion that was already taking place in conversation/writing.

The second sentence or question seems better grammatically, but like Jon Hanna I think it is too formal.

I think there are two ways you can put it in writing:

- Simply quoting it.
- By narrating it, maybe in some different words. Like, *he jokingly/sarcastically remarked about war being a way to celebrate peace*, or, *he asked sarcastically if there was some better way to celebrate peace than war*.